# Check if a specific cache tag exists

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-5.4

To check if a cache key exists, you can do this in Laravel:

```
use Cache;

if (Cache::has('key_name')) {
    // continue
}
```

Is there a way to do the same for **tags**?

```
// ! Pseudo code
if (Cache::hasTag('tag_name')) {
    // continue
}
```

Or, at least, to know whether there are any keys tagged with a specific tag?

```
// ! Pseudo code
if (Cache::tags('tag_name')->count() > 0) {
    // continue
}
```

Comment: So isn't `count(Cache::tags(['tag_name'])->get()) > 0` working ?

Comment: Nope. The `get()` method [needs](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Contracts/Cache/Store.html#method_get) an argument. I tested it to be sure.

Comment: I'm not really sure whether this would work `in_array('tag_name', Cache::getNames())` as [`getNames()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Cache/TagSet.html#method_getNames) is a method of class `Illuminate\Cache\TagSet`

Comment: `Cache::getNames()` or `Cache::tags('my_tag')->getNames()`  throws: *Call to undefined method Illuminate\Cache\RedisStore::getNames()*. And using `TagSet::getNames()` throws: *Non-static method Illuminate\Cache\TagSet::getNames() should not be called statically*. I'm not sure how to use this method, or rather: how to use it in the context of the `Cache` facade.

Comment: `$tagset = new TagSet; dd($tagset->getNames());` ?